# Convert nested object

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

What is best way to convert ... ?

```
const obj = {
  A: { B: [0, 0, 0, 0] },
  D: {
    B: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    C: [0, 0, 0, 0]
  }
}
```

to

```
const obj = {
  "A - B": [0, 0, 0, 0],
  "D - B": [0, 0, 0, 0],
  "D - C": [0, 0, 0, 0]
}
```

Thanks for your attention

Edit: my bad. I fixed question. Need all pairs for nested object. Depth is constant

Comment: The best way is a way with which you get the result you need. What have you tried so far?

Comment: An object can have only one property with a given name; there cannot be two "D" properties in the same object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) and [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) to do that.

```js
const obj = {
  A: {
    B: [0, 0, 0, 0]
  },
  D: {
    B: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    C: [0, 0, 0, 0]
  }
};

var result = Object.entries(obj).reduce((acc, [key, value]) => {
  Object.entries(value).forEach(([subKey, subValue]) => {
    acc[key + ' - ' + subKey] = subValue;
  });

  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(result);
```

Comment: Nice. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

### Basic solution

One possibility:

```js
const convert = (obj) => 
  Object.entries (obj)
    .reduce ((a, [k1, v]) => Object .keys (v) .reduce ((a, k2) => ({
      ...a,
      [`${k1} - ${k2}`]: v [k2]
    }), a), {})

const obj = {A: { B: [0, 0, 0, 0] }, D: {B: [0, 0, 0, 0], C: [0, 0, 0, 0]}}

console .log (convert (obj))
```

### Deeper paths

But it wouldn't be terribly hard to create a version which worked recursively at any depth.

```js
// helper
const findLeafPaths = (o, path = [[]]) => 
  typeof o == 'object' && !(Array.isArray(o))
    ? Object .entries (o) .flatMap (
        ([k, v]) => findLeafPaths (v, path).map(p => [k, ...p])
      ) 
    : path

// main function
const convert= (obj) => 
  findLeafPaths (obj) .reduce ((a, ps) => ({
    ...a, 
    [ps.join(' - ')]: ps .reduce ((o, p) => (o || {}) [p], obj)
  }), {})

// demonstration
const obj = {
  A: { B: [0, 0, 0, 0] },
  D: {
    B: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    C: [0, 0, 0, 0],
    E: {
      F: 42
    }
  }
}

console .log (convert (obj))
```

This uses a helper function. `findLeafPaths` finds the paths to all leaf nodes in an object: `findLeafPaths({a: {b: {c: 1, d: 2, e: 3}, f: 4}, g: 5})` returns `[['a', 'b', 'c'], ['a', 'b', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'e'], ['a', 'f'], ['g']]`.  The main function uses this to find the leaf paths, join them into a single string and create an object that has those keys associated with the appropriate value from your original object.

Answer (score 1):

You could take a dynamic approach for any dept of nested objects by storing the path and base object and the actual object.

```js
function deleteNested(object, path = [], base = object) {
    Object.entries(object).forEach(([k, v]) => {
        if (v && typeof v === 'object' && !Array.isArray(v)) {
            deleteNested(v, [...path, k], base);
        } else {
            base[[...path, k].join(' - ')] = v;
            delete base[path[0]];
        }
    });
}

const obj = { A: { B: [0, 0, 0, 0] }, D: { B: [0, 0, 0, 0], C: [0, 0, 0, 0] } };

deleteNested(obj);
console.log(obj);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```